# How to generate iOS app bundle in React Native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to generate an app bundle in React Native for iOS I am not sure how to. I found the following but it's for android

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle
```

Answer (score -1):

Below are the documentation links which can help you set up and deploy the app.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

https://reactnative.dev/docs/publishing-to-app-store